# Checked Radio Input not triggering :checked pseudo-selector

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom, css-selectors

### Main question:

How can the checked style not be active when the element is clearly checked as per the markup?

#### Context:

I ran into this issue yesterday and solved it with an ugly hack but would rather understand it better.

For starters, this is the rendered markup:

```
<fieldset id="Påbyggnad/Omskolning *" class="RadioButton-module_RadioButtons__3slSm">
  <div class="RadioButton-module_RadioButton__1Ftxu">
    <label for="Påbyggnad i tidigare yrkesinriktning">Påbyggnad i tidigare yrkesinriktning</label>
    <input id="Påbyggnad i tidigare yrkesinriktning" name="Omskolning" type="radio" value="false" disabled="" checked="">
  </div>
  <div class="RadioButton-module_RadioButton__1Ftxu">
    <label for="Omskolning i ny yrkesinriktning">Omskolning i ny yrkesinriktning</label>
    <input id="Omskolning i ny yrkesinriktning" name="Omskolning" type="radio" value="true" disabled=""> 
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

As we can see, the first input is **checked**, and both inputs are **disabled**.

Despite this, only the CSS associated with the **disabled** pseudo-selectors is active:

```
.RadioButton-module_RadioButtonGroup__ZHytl .RadioButton-module_RadioButtons__3slSm :disabled {
    background-color: #dde0e7;
    border: 1px solid #a2a4aa;
    cursor: unset;
}
```

Relevant snippet of (SCSS) stylesheet:

```
:disabled {
  background-color: $disabled-color;
  border: 1px solid $gray-2;
  cursor: unset;
}
:disabled:checked {
  background-color: $gray-1;
  border: 1px solid $gray-2;
}
```

#### Further context:

We are using **React** and **defaultChecked**. See partial implementation below:

```
export const RadioButton = ({
  label,
  id = label,
  defaultChecked,
  onClick,
  onChange,
  testSelector,
  name,
  value,
  onBlur,
  disabled,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={s.RadioButton}>
      <label htmlFor={id} className={s.RadioButtonLabel}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        className={s.RadioInput}
        disabled={disabled}
        defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
        id={id}
        onClick={onClick}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        data-testid={testSelector}
        type="radio"
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Due to the way the component is rendered, it is not atypical it is rerendered 6 times in a very short timespan (probably not ideal in itself, but lets focus on the main question instead!). When **defaultChecked** evaluates to `true` or `false` in one of the first 5 renders, that value appears to be persisted throughout other renders, whereas null/undefined evaluation is replaced by the first  `true`/`false` evaluation, which typically appears in the 3rd render.

It seems very reasonable that **defaultChecked** is defined by its first non-nullish value, but then there are conflicting states:

- Markup says `checked`
- Stylesheet says not checked
- defaultChecked appears to say not checked, yet the markup which is a function of the does not reflect this?

How can the markup display `checked` if the input is indeed not checked?

P.S. The "ugly hack" used to solve this was to ensure that defaultChecked is never evaluated to a non-nullish value during the early renders.